# How to clone children in React

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to write a simple component, that does clone its children and add a `marginBottom: 30` to it.

This does work great using `<View>` as sibling. Unfortunately it does not work using a component as sibling.

**CustomListItem component:**

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: React.Node,
};

/**
 *
 */
function CustomListItem ({ children }: Props) {
  return React.Children.map(children, child => {
    const style = [
      child.props.style,
      { marginBottom: 30 },
    ];
    return React.cloneElement(child, { style });
  });
}

export default CustomListItem;
```

**Outcome using the component:**

```
// works
<CustomListItem>
    <Text>This is great.</Text>
</CustomListItem>

// works as well
<CustomListItem>
    <View>
        <CustomComponent></CustomComponent>
    </View>
</CustomListItem>

// does not work. Why?
<CustomListItem>
    <CustomComponent></CustomComponent>
</CustomListItem>
```

This is the CustomComponent I've been using for testing purposes:

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

type Props = {
  children: React.Node,
};

function CustomComponent(props: Props) {
  return <View>{props.children}</View>;
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

It does not matter if I insert a `<Text>` or `<View>` element as a child of my `<CustomComponent>`, so I did not insert this in this example.

Comment: To avoid any confusion I have added the most simple component possible to the question.

Comment: Why using clone instead using HoC to generate components ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I do not now how to use HoC yet, so clone was my best approach so far.

Comment: HoCs are simply function that returns decorated component, way much  simpler than manage cloning.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini thanks for the suggestion. I am reading about this right now. To be honest its quite hard to dive in, as I am not an experienced developer with javascript. If you can, it would be great, if you could provide an example using my case. Afterwards it would be easy to reuse and manipulate it.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Wouldn't be much better since `child` is *already* an element, not a component class or function. Then you would have to get the display name of the component in the HOC.

Comment: even before being an element, child *is* a component, if you can customize how your component instatantiate, you don't need to clone and there is no benefit in this

Comment: The accepted answer is a HoC, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your component does not delegate the style prop. In React in general, passing `style` to a custom component doesn't style it automatically, you have to manually set it up:

```
type Props = {
  children: React.Node,
  style: object
};

function CustomComponent(props: Props) {
  return <View style={props.style}>{props.children}</View>;
}
```

This will capture the `style` property from `props` and apply it to the wrapping `View`.

---

You *could* use a higher order component, but it would turn out pretty much the same, though you could make it more reusable:

```
const withStyles = (component, style) => React.cloneElement(component, { style });
```

Then use it as:

```
return withStyles(child, style);
```

Usually HOCs have a reference *to the actual  component function or class like `CustomComponent`*, not an already created element. But in this case, you don't so they're not that helpful.

Comment: CustomComponent is also a HoC with fixed component.